# How to create temporary result set from selected set of data in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

For debugging purpose I want to create pseudo "result set" in order to join them, like:

```
with tmp_tbl as ( select v from dual where v in ('cat', 'dog', 'fish') )
select read_tbl.* from tmp_tbl
  left outer join read_tbl on real_tbl.id = tmp_tbl.id;
```

I understand that above expression is invalid and can be transformed into another which works. But my real example too complicate to shown here.

My question how to make this expression:

```
select v from dual where v in ('cat', 'dog', 'fish')
```

a valid result set so I can use it with **joins** and **from** keywords?

**dual** doesn't have v column. I look for a way to break SQL syntax to avoid **create table** calls..

Comment: Your example is mostly invalid because it's missing an `AS` clause - `with tmp_bls as ( select ... )` though there are other issues like not having a `from` clause, and your use of double quotes, which I'm confused about - as well as whether `dial` is a real table with those values or if you've misspelled `dual`. Do you want a dummy table with those three fixed values?

Comment: Also, should be `('cat', 'dog', 'fish')`, not `("cat", "dog", "fish")`, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes, sorry  I fix these minor issues...

Comment: So is `dial` a real table, or are you trying to generate those fixed values as if they were coming from a table?

Comment: Is `dial` an actual table? If so, you are selecting one column `v` but you are referencing `v.id` by way of `tmp_tbl.id`. Or are you seeking to explode `('cat', 'dog', 'fish')` into rows?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes! As if they come from table!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to do, but it looks to me like you want a dummy table with fixed values. If so you can select multiple dummy values from `dual` and `union all` the results, which will give you multiple rows. You can then use that as a sub-select, or if you're effectively masking a real table (from the 'debug' comment) then a CTE might be clearer:

```
with tmp_tbl as (
  select 'cat' as id from dual
  union all select 'dog' from dual
  union all select 'fish' from dual
)
select tmp_tbl.id, read_tbl.*
from tmp_tbl
left outer join real_tbl
on real_tbl.id = tmp_tbl.id;
```

You referred to a `v` column in the text, but you're joining on `id`, so I've aliased the fixed value as `id` inside the CTE (it only needs to be named in the first row). You can just change that to something else if you prefer. And you can of course select several fixed values (with different aliases) in each select from `dual` to make it look more like a real table.

Comment: Wow! Great! Seems that syntax not so compact, but do job! +1

Comment: @gavenkoa You can shrink the temp table syntax like this: `select column_value id from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('cat', 'dog', 'fish'));`

Comment: @jonearles - nice. I got the impression that multiple columns might be needed in the real version, but that's a neat way to do a single column.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can use [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142), also known as “the with clause”

```
with t as
( select v from dial where v in ('cat','dog','fish') )
Select * from t
```

Oracle may decide to materialize this result set internally or not. If you want to control this behavior, you can use the optimizer hints “materialize” and “inline”.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Note that I wrote about expression *select v from dial where v in* that it is invalid. As **dual** doesn't have *v* column. I look for a way to break SQL syntax to avoid **create table** calls...

Comment: Ah. now I understand. You misspelled dual twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose the query in brackets and give it a name, than you can use it in joins as you wish:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( select v from dial where v in ('cat', 'dog', 'fish')  ) tmp_table
  JOIN other_table ON tmp_table.v = other_table.v
 WHERE tmp_table.v = xxx etc
```

Comment: Sorry, question about another thing... How to make *virtual* table from selected set of values without **create table** and **insert**... **dual** is *special* table from Oracle and doesn't have *v* column...